# SQL Error Code 6550, Error Message: ORA-06550

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-ords, oracle-autonomous-db

I have an ORDS 'PUT' procedure called "update_player". When I run my code (C#) I get the following message:

> "cause": "An error occurred when evaluating the SQL statement associated with this resource. SQL Error Code 6550, Error Message: ORA-06550: line 2, column 28:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPDATE_PLAYER'\nORA-06550: line 2, column 28:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored\n",

When I evaluate the stated line I cannot see anything wrong.

> (2) p_playerid IN players.playerid%TYPE, (believe this is the correct line)

I build this ORDS solution based on this excellent document [Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) : Create Basic RESTful Web Services Using PL/SQL](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-create-basic-rest-web-services-using-plsql)

I do get the POST to work.

As well as I understand this here is the procedure that I believe this error comes from:

```
PROCEDURE update_player (
  p_playerid IN players.playerid%TYPE,
  p_playername IN players.playername%TYPE,
  p_registrationDate IN VARCHAR2,
  p_dateLastmatch IN VARCHAR2,
  p_previousMatchDate IN VARCHAR2,
  p_nrofdayssincelastactivity IN players.nrofdayssincelastactivity%TYPE,
  p_lastmatchid IN players.lastmatchid%TYPE,
  p_diffandround IN players.diffandround%TYPE,
  p_nrsingleplayermatches IN players.nrsingleplayermatches%TYPE,
  p_nrmultiplayermatches IN players.nrmultiplayermatches%TYPE,
  p_nrmatches IN players.nrmatches%TYPE,
  p_nrquitmatches IN players.nrquitmatches%TYPE,
  p_nrflips IN players.nrflips%TYPE,
  p_nrclicks IN players.nrclicks%TYPE,
  p_totmatchtimesec IN players.totmatchtimesec%TYPE,
  p_score IN players.score%TYPE,
  p_nrwonmatches IN players.nrwonmatches%TYPE,
  p_nrlostmatches IN players.nrlostmatches%TYPE,
  p_nrevenmatches IN players.nrevenmatches%TYPE,
  p_templnrmatches IN players.templnrmatches%TYPE,
  p_templmatchtimesec IN players.templmatchtimesec%TYPE,
  p_isqualified IN players.isqualified%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE PLAYERS SET
  --playerid = p_playerid,
  playername = p_playername,
  registrationdate = TO_DATE(p_registrationdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI'),
  datelastmatch = TO_DATE(p_datelastmatch, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI'),
  previousmatchdate = TO_DATE(p_previousmatchdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI'),
  nrofdayssincelastactivity = p_nrofdayssincelastactivity,
  lastmatchid = p_lastmatchid,
  diffandround = p_diffandround,
  nrsingleplayermatches = p_nrsingleplayermatches,
  nrmultiplayermatches = p_nrmultiplayermatches,
  nrmatches = p_nrmatches,
  nrquitmatches = p_nrquitmatches,
  nrflips = p_nrflips,
  nrclicks = p_nrclicks,
  totmatchtimesec = p_totmatchtimesec,
  score = p_score,
  nrwonmatches = p_nrwonmatches,
  nrlostmatches = p_nrlostmatches,
  nrevenmatches = p_nrevenmatches,
  templnrmatches = p_templnrmatches,
  templmatchtimesec = p_templmatchtimesec,
  isqualified = p_isqualified
WHERE playerid = p_playerid;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
HTP.print(SQLERRM);
END;
```

Here is the handler SQL:

```
BEGIN
                       update_player(
   playerid                  => :playerid,
   playername                => :playername,
   registrationdate          => :registrationdate,
   datelastmatch             => :datelastmatch,
   previousmatchdate         => :previousmatchdate,
   nrofdayssincelastactivity => :nrofdayssincelastactivity,
   lastmatchid               => :lastmatchid,
   diffandround              => :diffandround,
   nrsingleplayermatches     => :nrsingleplayermatches,
   nrmultiplayermatches      => :nrmultiplayermatches,
   nrmatches                 => :nrmatches,
   nrquitmatches             => :nrquitmatches,
   nrflips                   => :nrflips,
   nrclicks                  => :nrclicks,
   totmatchtimesec           => :totmatchtimesec,
   score                     => :score,
   nrwonmatches              => :nrwonmatches,
   nrlostmatches             => :nrlostmatches,
   nrevenmatches             => :nrevenmatches,
   templnrmatches            => :templnrmatches,
   templmatchtimesec         => :templmatchtimesec,
   isqualified               => :isqualified);
 END;
```

Here is the json definition I use:

```
    playerRecord.playerid = "583CA078CA47D87";   
    playerRecord.playername = "Maria";
    playerRecord.registrationdate = "7/1/2022 10:33";
    playerRecord.datelastmatch = "9/7/2022 11:00";
    playerRecord.previousmatchdate = "8/7/2022 11:00";
    playerRecord.nrofdayssincelastactivity = 1;
    playerRecord.lastmatchid = "LASTMATCHID";
    playerRecord.diffandround = "D1R1";
    playerRecord.nrsingleplayermatches = 9;
    playerRecord.nrmultiplayermatches = 33;
    playerRecord.nrmatches = 136;
    playerRecord.nrquitmatches = 0;
    playerRecord.nrflips = 2022;
    playerRecord.nrclicks = 4444;
    playerRecord.totmatchtimesec = 9999;
    playerRecord.score = 5555;
    playerRecord.nrwonmatches = 20;
    playerRecord.nrlostmatches = 10;
    playerRecord.nrevenmatches = 3;
    playerRecord.templnrmatches = 0;
    playerRecord.templmatchtimesec = 0;
    playerRecord.isqualified = 0;
```

I hava also tested with "8-7-2022 11:00" date format.

```
CREATE TABLE PLAYERS (
  playerID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  playerName VARCHAR2(20),
  registrationDate DATE,
  dateLastMatch DATE,
  previousMatchDate DATE,
  nrOfDaysSinceLastActivity INT,
  lastMatchId VARCHAR(12),
  diffAndRound VARCHAR2(4),
  nrSingleplayerMatches INT,
  nrMultiplayerMatches INT,
  nrMatches INT,
  nrQuitMatches INT,
  nrFlips INT,
  nrClicks INT,
  totMatchTimeSec FLOAT,
  score INT,
  nrWonMatches INT,
  nrLostMatches INT,
  nrEvenMatches INT,
  templNrMatches INT,
  templMatchTimeSec INT,
  isQualified INT
);
```

Comment: Can't do much w/o the PLAYERS table DDL

Answer (score 0):

In the procedure you have:

```
PROCEDURE update_player (
  p_playerid IN players.playerid%TYPE,
  p_playername IN players.playername%TYPE,
  p_registrationDate IN VARCHAR2,
  p_dateLastmatch IN VARCHAR2,
...
```

But the handler has the following code

```
BEGIN
                       update_player(
   playerid                  => :playerid,
   playername                => :playername,
   registrationdate          => :registrationdate,
   datelastmatch             => :datelastmatch,
...
```

The handler should be

```
BEGIN
                       update_player(
   p_playerid                  => :playerid,
   p_playername                => :playername,
   p_registrationdate          => :registrationdate,
   p_datelastmatch             => :datelastmatch,
...
```

Generally debugging an ORA-6550 is a 3 step process:

First Comment out all arguments in procedure/function and in call to procedure.

1. Test
2. Fix errors if any
3. Uncomment the first commented argument in both procedure/function and in call. Compile. Back to 1. and proceed

Comment: I did solve it finally with the help of @thatjeffsmith. It was the dates in the code vs. the database.

Comment: Pls put in a comment or close the question to indicate it was answered. Saves others the time of writing up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @thatjeffsmith this problem was solved. It was the format of the dates that caused the error despite it did not look like that.